# How to pass an array value to Router.navTo in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have this call in a SAPUI5 code. Before the soldTo was a simple comboBox, but I changed it for a multiComboBox. So, now this.soldTo is an array.

```
            this._oRouter.navTo("SearchResult", {
                soldTo: this.soldTo,
                shipTo: this.shipTo,
            }, false);
```

The routing in manifest.json is defined like this:

```
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "viewPath": "com.openOrder.AM.view",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "controlId": "app",
            "clearControlAggregation": false
        },
        "routes": [
            {
                "name": "RouteApp",
                "pattern": "",
                "target": [
                    "Search"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "{soldTo}/{shipTo}/SearchResult",
                "name": "SearchResult",
                "target": [
                    "SearchResult"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "ResultDetails",
                "pattern": "{}/ResultDetails",
                "target": [
                    "ResultDetails"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "targets": {
            "Search": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "clearControlAggregation": false,
                "viewName": "Search",
                "viewLevel": 1
            },
            "SearchResult": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "clearControlAggregation": false,
                "viewName": "SearchResult",
                "viewLevel": 2
            },
            "ResultDetails": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "clearControlAggregation": false,
                "viewName": "ResultDetails",
                "viewLevel": 3
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error after change.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')"

Does anyone has an exemple how to pass the multiComboBox values to the function Router.navTo, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to send the array with a URL. The URL makes only sense if you want a unique address for a specific record. Therefore you should pass it with the model on your component.

Define your model in the manifest. The definition will enable you to access it using "this.getModel(""). In your views you can access the model with "this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("").